# I need help creating a border around a checkbox form

Tags: html

I need help creating a border around a checkbox form

I know it can be done like the image above but I can't figure out how to make the 1px solid black border stop when it hits the `<p>` and skip going through it like in the image above.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a visually organized and accessible form using the `fieldset` element.

The `legend` element is used to provide a caption for the group of form controls.

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Gender</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="male">
    <label for="male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="female">
    <label for="female">Female</label>
</fieldset>
```

Experience it yourself by visiting this interactive example:

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=html&file=fieldset-tag